# Building a serverless secure MMO auction house system with Lambda + DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm building an auction house system for an MMO, the system is pretty straightforward:

- Players can post items to sell, item will be retained inside the order and appear on the market
- Players can post items to buy, gold will be retained inside the order and system will look for orders, if there is a match, it will swap.

We're considering using AWS to make things simpler to scale. But, we're also having some concerns in matter of security, since any hacks on the auction house would pretty much ruin the game. And, well, since it's an online game, there will be people trying to hack it pretty much from day 1.

Is the serverless architecture recommended for this type of system in terms of security? Are there any unforeseen problems I might run in the future?

Is NoSQL(DynamoDB) recommended for this? I can visualize relational databases keeping things a bit more secure because of integrity restriction and ACID, but I'm a bit uncomfortable with having my code handling all the relationships in such a critical software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For the DB architecture:**

I think the key point here is your `system will look for orders, if there is a match` sentence. What matters is your indexing to achieve this. If you can create an index that is `good` (has a large number of distinct values that are requested fairly uniformly) then those items in the mall would be less costly and fast for querying. Otherwise searching items in the mall will be very inefficient, for instance, if your index key is say GoldenSword and 10000+ of items have the same id GoldenSword. I don't know the requirements for your 'Auction house' like in how many ways you can search or add so I can't speculate much on this. But a downside is if your DB architecture changes in time or is weakly designed at first it forces you to use Global Secondary Indexes and become very costly as DynamoDB is costly it self.

[Best practices for DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/BestPractices.html)

**For the safety:**

It is very fine and secure if you have decent restrictions on your IAM Roles and policies for accessing dynamoDB and for running lambda on your AWS account. Not like giving full access to everything and all dynamoDB operations and tables. As long as your IAM credentials are safe they will be safe. Never seen a security issue regarding to serverless architecture. Plus DynamoDB has a easy to use encryption at rest feature.